# bbPress automatically replaces a url with html link, inside crayon

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, bbpress

I am using crayon plugin and bbPress plugin in WordPress. bbPress allows you to use forums inside WordPress. after adding a new topic in bbPress, I noticed that the normal url is being replaced with an html link. This is because I wrote the url inside crayon code. If I write the url outside the crayon code, it is not replaced with a link. So the problem seems with the crayon plugin.
For example: inside crayon plugin I wrote `http://www.example.com`
It is replaced with `<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow">http://example.com</a>`

Please help!